# Vim-latex's three character shortcut for align*

Tags: vim-latex

What is the shortcut in Vim-latex for the align* environment? For the regular align environment, I just type in EAL. I've tried a few combinations for align* but those did not work. Is there a three character shortcut for the align* environment (not using F5)?

Comment: The whole point of F5 in Vim LaTeX is to make environment creation easier. If you really don't want to use F5 then remapping would be my best guess.

Comment: There is none by default. Give  me a bit and I'll get it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no shortcut for it by deafault. To set it up for yourself, you can use the following command

```
:call IMAP("EA*", "\<C-r>=Tex_PutEnvironment('align*')\<CR>", 'tex')
```

This sets the shortcut to EA*. Change the first argument if you want something else. Getting it to work for visual mode is more challenging.

If you have access to the files in your vim runtime, then you can add the following line to envmacros.vim (part of the latexsuite distribution) around the place that the other Math environments are defined.

```
call s:Tex_EnvMacros('EA*', '&Math.', 'align*')
```

where the first argument again is the shortcut.

EDIT:

I checked on github, and the newest version of latex-suite has the shortcut set as EAS (for insert mode).